# Finding the stationary distribution from the generator matrix

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, solution-verification, markov-process, stationary-processes

**Question**

Consider a Markov process $\{X(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ with state space $$S = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$$ and generator matrix
$$Q =
\begin{pmatrix}
-q_0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
2 & -q_1 & 4 & 0\\
0 & 4 & -q_2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -q_3
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Find the stationary distribution $\pi_Q$ associated with $Q$.

**My working**

I first fully determine the generator matrix to be
$$Q =
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
2 & -6 & 4 & 0\\
0 & 4 & -6 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix},$$
using the fact that the rows must sum to $0$.

Now, I also know that $\pi_Q$ must satisfy $$\pi_QQ = 0,$$ yielding the following system of linear equations:
\begin{align}
-2\pi_0 + 2\pi_1 & = 0, \tag{1}\\
2\pi_0 - 6\pi_1 + 4\pi_2 & = 0, \tag{2}\\
4\pi_1 - 6\pi_2 + \pi_3 & = 0, \tag{3}\\
2\pi_2 - \pi_3 & = 0, \tag{4}
\end{align}
where summing $(3)$ and $(4)$ gives $$\pi_1 = \pi_2,$$ which can then be substituted into $(2)$ to return $$\pi_0 = \pi_1.$$ Thus, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\pi_0 & = \pi_1\\
& = \pi_2
\end{aligned}$$
and from $(4)$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\pi_3 & = 2\pi_2\\
& = 2\pi_0.
\end{aligned}$$
Finally, recalling that $$\pi_0 + \pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 = 1$$ means that $$\pi_Q = \left(\frac 1 5, \frac 1 5, \frac 1 5, \frac 2 5\right).$$

However, this $\pi_Q$ clearly does not satisfy $$\pi_QQ = 0.$$ Did I go wrong when I assumed that there are no absorbing states when in fact, there could be? If so, then how should I solve for the stationary distribution? Do I leave my answer in terms of $q_0, q_1, q_2$ and $q_3$? Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You went wrong in your checking step; your distribution is correct.

Comment: @Ian Okay I am just dog-tired. I was thinking that the pre-multiplication of $\pi_Q$ to $Q$ must equal $1$. Doing mathematics at 3 am in the middle of the night is not good for me... cries... My apologies for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned kindly in a comment, I simply went wrong in my verification step. Now thinking back, I believe I was erroneously checking for $$\pi_QQ = 1$$ and not $$\pi_QQ = 0.$$